# Laravel 4.2 Many-to-many relationship : Can't read from pivot table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4, many-to-many

I was trying to apply Jeffrey Way's many-to-many relationships tutorial into my private messaging app but I got stuck. I'm trying to get 2 conversations, `haha` and `hehe` which are associated to a user.  However, Laravel gives me the error :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Conversations.user_id' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Conversations` where `Conversations`.`user_id` = 1)
```

I have these data in my conversations table :

```
+---------+----------+
| conv_id | name     |
+---------+----------+
|       1 |     haha |
|       2 |     hehe |
+---------+----------+
```

In my user_conversations table :

```
+----+-------------+--------+
| id | conv_id     | user_id|
+----+-------------+--------+
|  1 |           1 |      1 |
|  2 |           2 |      1 |
+----+-------------+--------+
```

**1. I've tried :** In controllers :

**User** : `return $this->belongsToMany('User','id');`

**Conversatons** : `return $this->hasMany('Conversations','conv_id');`

but the result I got was : `haha` instead of `haha` and `hehe`

**2. I've also tried :**

**User** : `return $this->belongsToMany('User','user_conversations');`

**Conversatons** : `return $this->hasMany('Conversations','user_conversations');`

but laravel returned me the following error :

```
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'Conversations.user_conversations' in 'where clause' (SQL: select * from `Conversations` where `Conversations`.`user_conversations` = 1)
```

I'm still relatively new in Laravel so I might be making some silly mistakes.

---

here are my codes :

**MODEL**

**Conversations**

```
class Conversations extends Eloquent  {

    protected $table = 'Conversations';

    protected $fillable = array('name');

    public function users(){
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }

}
```

**User**

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Auth\UserInterface;
use Illuminate\Auth\Reminders\RemindableInterface;

class User extends Eloquent implements UserInterface, RemindableInterface {

    ....

    public function conversations(){
        return $this->hasMany('Conversations');
    }
}
```

**CONTROLLERS**

**Conversations Controller**

```
public function create()
    {
        $loginuser = User::find(Auth::user()->id);
        $conversations = $loginuser->conversations;
        return View::make('msgsystem.Conversations.Conversations',array('conversations'=>$conversations));
    }
```

**MIGRATIONS (in function up())**

**user**

```
Schema::create('users',function($table)
        {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->string('password',100);
            $table->string('name',150);
            $table->string('usertype',50);
            $table->boolean('block');
            $table->string('remember_token',100);
            $table->timestamp('lastlogin_at');
            $table->timestamps();
            $table->softDeletes();
        });
```

**conversations**

```
Schema::create('Conversations', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('conv_id')->index();
            $table->string('name',100);
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

**user_conversations**

```
Schema::create('user_conversations', function(Blueprint $table)
        {
            $table->increments('id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('conversation_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('conversation_id')->references('conv_id')->on('conversations')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned()->index();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

---

Bonus points for improvement of code. Thank you very much!

Comment: If it's a many-to-many relationship you trying to implement, both your User and Conversations models should be belongsToMany.

Comment: @Jeemusu Yup, you're right. I was about to answer my question as I just recently found it out when I looked through Mr. Way's tutorial again. Maybe you can answer it and explain further why hasMany-belongsToMany does not entitle to a many-to-many relationship? Thank you!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your example of a many to many relationship a user can have many conversations, where the conversations can also be shared by many users.

In this case we need to use the `belongsToMany()` method for both the relationship on the user model, and the inverse on the conversations model.

```
class User 
{
    public function conversations()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Conversations');
    }
}



class Conversations 
{
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User');
    }
}
```

If you need to use a different name for your pivot table, or override the associated keys, you can pass them in as optional arguments.

```
return $this->belongsToMany(
   'Conversations',          // related_table
   'user_conversations',     // pivot_table
   'user_id',                // key_1
   'conversations_id'        // key_2
);
```

Comment: thank you! Btw, may I know why hasMany-belongsToMany does not work? It sounds correct, isn't it, that User hasMany conversations and a conversations belongsToMany Users?

Comment: In `hasMany`, more than one `foo` may be binded to only one `bar`, but in `belongsToMany`, a foo binded to a `bar` may also be binded to another one, let's say `baz`. Using `hasMany` would not suit there. A user may have more than one conversations, and a conversation may be between more than one users.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it will help someone. I lost many hours and then look to database...

I forgot **set 'deleted_at' default value to NULL** (when use soft delete).